# How to disable Connected Standby in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sleep, power-management, hybrid-sleep

I have a tablet that runs Windows 8 Pro. Microsoft came up with a new power mode that they call *Connected Standby*, in which evidently all non-Metro apps are suspended when the tablet is put in a lower power mode (that is most of the time for a portable device.) The issue with this is that none of my desktop apps can wake it on schedule (including Microsoft's own Task Scheduler.)

So my question is, how can you disable Connected Standby?

Comment: There is no way to disable Connected Standby.  Somebody did find a solution of sorts though [here](http://mobilitydigest.com/connected-standby-be-damned-a-sort-of-workaround/)

Comment: Is your question "How do I disable it", or "How do I wake form this sleep mode via a Desktop App"?  If you're using a low-power CPU (say, an Intel Atom), then it can't be disabled.  :/

Comment: @techie007: Well, I guess I'm asking both questions. I read somewhere that my desktop apps cannot wake the tablet because of connected standby. So now I'm curious about the Atom CPU you mentioned. Can you explain why Atom CPU is the issue?

Comment: First, try to keep the number of questions per Question to one please -- this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. :)  As for the (newer) Atom CPUs, it's because it's a low-power chip that supports/uses Connected Standby _in place of_ regular Standby.

Comment: @techie007: I did a quick search and I can't seem to find a connection between connected standby and the hardware i.e CPU. All I get is that it's a Microsoft feature.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402370/lowpoweraudio-whitepaper.pdf

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimizing-windows-8-applications-for-connected-standby

Comment: @techie007: It says, `It is part of the Microsoft certification...` and not the other way around. That is why I thought that there's a way to disable it (since it's dictated by the software manufacturer.)

Comment: Basically the newer Atom's (other CPUs as well I'm sure ;) support the tech needed to utilize, and be certified for, Connected Standby.  Because the CPU supports it, it's what's used instead of regular Standby.

Comment: @techie007: Yeah, thanks. I understand that. But as Ramhound's link shows it doesn't always work as Microsoft wants it. It sucks that there's no way to disable it and use the old S3, S4 power modes instead...

Answer (score 6):

Open `regedit.exe`, go to `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\` and set the value `CsEnabled` from `1` to `0`.

**Source:**

[http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-slate-tablets/How-to-disable-connected-standby/m-p/1367197/highlight/true#M27364](https://web.archive.org/web/20140910212652/http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-slate-tablets/How-to-disable-connected-standby/m-p/1367197/highlight/true#M27364)

Comment: Thanks. Good find. Although as they pointed out -- it just takes out the "Sleep" option from the power menu.

Answer (score 1):

I believe also installing Hyper-V will disable it

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2014/06/23/disabling-hyperv-on-surface-pro-3-so-connected-standby-will-work-or-not-work-depending-on-your-mood.aspx